# Draw a border around a UITableviewCell when selected with UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to update UITableViewCell's border when the user performs a long press gesture on the cell, but it's not updating.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
let objLongPressHandler = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressHandler(_:)))
objLongPressHandler.view?.tag = indexPath.row
objLongPressHandler.delegate = self
objLongPressHandler.enabled = true
objLongPressHandler.minimumPressDuration = 0.1

cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(objLongPressHandler)
```

This is my function `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` function.

```
func longPressHandler(objGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let center = objGesture.view?.center
    let rootViewPoint = objGesture.view!.superview?.convertPoint(center!, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(rootViewPoint!)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! GroupTableViewCell
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 3
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: What is `objGesture`? Is it a gesture recogniser? Where is this code being called? What results do you get for each line of the code (i.e. what values do you get for `center`, `rootViewPoint`, `indexPath`, and `cell`)

Comment: I am getting right indexpath with this code. And I'm callling code in cellforIRowatIndexPath

Comment: If I understand correctly - you want the cell border to change when the user performs a long press on the cell. Only the cell which has the long press should change. Is this correct?

Comment: Perfect, that's much clearer now. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Multiple gesture recognisers are not necessary. Use a single long tap gesture recogniser on the main view for the view controller.
2. When handling the gesture, convert the location to table view coordinates using `locationInView`. Get the selected row by calling `tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint`.
3. Loop through the visible rows in the table view. If the row is at the selected index  path then show the border, otherwise remove the border.

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Install tap gesture recogniser on main view.
    let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressHandler(_:)))
    gesture.enabled = true
    gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.1

    view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

func longPressHandler(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    // Get the location of the gesture relative to the table view.
    let location = gesture.locationInView(tableView)

    // Determine the row where the touch occurred.
    guard let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) else {
        return
    }

    // Iterate through all visible rows.
    guard let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else {
        return
    }

    for indexPath in indexPaths {

        // Get the cell for each visible row.
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else {
            continue
        }

        // If the index path is for the selected cell, then show the highlighted border, otherwise remove the border.
        let layer = cell.contentView.layer

        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
            layer.borderWidth = 3
        }
        else {
            layer.borderWidth = 0
        }

        cell.setNeedsLayout()
    }

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell #\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: but I'll need just set border to selected objects.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question to describe what you are trying to accomplish. Could you be more specific? I think you have gesture recogniser somewhere, is that correct? Are you trying to drag something over the table view? Or do you just want a border around the cells that the user has tapped on?

Comment: I edited my question.And I'm just trying to change border of selected object.But I need the change it in longpresshandler function.So first I getting cell and indexpath with center point and trying to change bordercolor but thats not change.